# Python MemoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a small script, generating a wordlist from given chars in python. But always gets a MemoryError after execution. Why is it stored in the ram? is there better way of code not using ram but giving a working output?

```
from itertools import product
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 
         'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 
         'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 
         'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 
         'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '1', '2', '3', 
         '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
length = 8
result = ["".join(item) for item in product(*[chars]*length)]
for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Comment: By the way, you can use a string: `chars = string.ascii_letters+string.digits` as well.

Answer (score 10):

By putting square brackets around your generator, you tell Python to turn it into an actual list, in-memory. You don't really need *all* of the elements at once, do you?

Instead, turn your square brackets into parentheses and Python will keep it a generator, which will yield items only when requested:

```
>>> ("".join(item) for item in product(*[chars]*length))
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x2d9cb40>
>>> ["".join(item) for item in product(*[chars]*length)]
[1]    3245 killed     ipython2
```

Take a look at the `string` module. It has a bunch of helpful constants:

```
import string
from itertools import product

chars = string.letters + string.digits
length = 8

result = (''.join(item) for item in product(*[chars], repeat=length))

for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Comment: You *can* use the `repeat` keyword to `product`: `product(*[chars], repeat=length)`.